# How do electric waves look in 3D?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I was reading a post about how EM Waves are formed when an electron is accelerated due to the kink formed in the outward radial electric field vector.
([http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~teviet/Waves/empulse_details.html](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/%7Eteviet/Waves/empulse_details.html)).

From the post, it seems like the propagation of EM waves due to an accelerated electron in 3D should be like that of spherical waves in vacuum. But, I don't know if this is what really happens.

Comment: An accelerated electron emits photons with certain frequencies. Billions of coherent photons can form light wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electromagnetic wave from an accelerating charge is not spherically symmetric in strength. For example, for a charge moving at non-relativistic speeds, the wave carries more power per solid angle in a direction perpendicular to the acceleration than in a direction parallel or antiparallel to it. (The angular dependence is proportional to $\sin^2\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle from the direction of acceleration.)

The fields of an arbitrarily moving point charge are known as the Liénard-Wiechert fields. You can find the mathematical details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) in Wikipedia.

If the charge has a sudden acceleration, the wave will travel outward in a spherical shell, but it won’t be equally strong in all directions.